# Advice on handling frontend User Inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I've been working with Ruby & RoR for a few weeks now and must say, this is a beautiful language, it's been very enjoyable to work with.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction for an article that explains collecting user inputs on the frontend, everything I've found so far has been confusing.

Basically, I want to create an input field in a front end view that passes the result to my controller so I can feed it to an API wrapper.

In irb I can do this, but I don't understand the equivalent for a view that's accessible on the front end.

```
customeremail = gets.chomp
ticketfind = Desk.customers(:email => customeremail)
```

I don't necessarily need to store the data in a database, I'd almost rather prefer not to. Basically just need the input to pass off to the API, so I can redirect to a form which I'll submit to the API. I'm certain I can figure it out with some good links, I just don't think I'm googling the right thing.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The `params` hash is how everything is passed around in rails. [See Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html). Also when learning rails I highly recommend [Michael Hartl's Tutorials](http://www.railstutorial.org/). they are easy to follow and highly informative.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a simple form on your view...

```
<%= form_tag "/my_controller/my_action" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag ":customer_email" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

This site explains about form_tag 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

And in your `my_controller` your `my_action` method...

```
def my_action
ticketfind = Desk.customers(:email => params[:customer_email])
```

Unlike Josh I prefer to use form helpers, but there's always more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When forms are submitted in HTML they create a POST request to the server based on the URL you pointed the form to. The server picks up the POST request and maps it to the controller via your route map.

Ex:

```
<!-- This will POST form data to localhost:3000/users/create --> 
<form action='users/create'>
    <input type='text'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

This should ping your server and route to `UsersController#create`. Rails stashes the form data in `params`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

I would recommend that you learn to do this *without* ERB first. Create a form with raw HTML so you can start to learn what's going on. You can use an ERB template, but only embed the variables in Ruby (e.g. don't use form helpers). You can then refactor to that (I personally prefer raw HTML over ERB heleprs). If you use Chrome or FF, you can open up the developer console and watch how the network requests work when you submit the form (I forget if this clears with each refresh or not, so you might not actually be able to do this in this example, but it's helpful in AJAX flows)

Comment: I agree with you about not using the erb, I've done enough forms in html so I'm very comfortable with handling them.

So if I want a text field, how do i define the variable I want? 

Above in Steve's example, he uses text_field_tag ":customer_email" with me fetching params[:customer_email] in the controller. How do I define the _:customer_email_ value in plain HTML

Comment: I want to say it's the name field. The "text_field_tag" command just spits out HTML (see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag)